# How to convert data which is received from udp to ctype struct in Python?

Tags: python, byte, tuples, ctypes, typeconverter

I'm using Python 2.7.6
ctypes struct:

```
class TestStruct(Structure):
   _fields_=[
          ("ValueA",c_int),
          ("StringA",c_char*9)
          ]
```

And I get datas from udp like this:

```
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                         socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((self.__ip,self.__port))
    print("Starting Receiving......")
    while True:
        try:
            (data,addr) = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            t = cast( data, POINTER(TestStruct))
            print t.ValueA
            #print(data[0])
            #print(type(data))
        except Exception,ex:
            print ex
            break
```

As you can see , I'm using "cast", but what it converted is the one whose type looks like:"**main**.LP_TestStruct".

I wanna get is TestStruct object , what function should I use ?
Thanks!

Comment: try `t1 = t.contents` and then `print t1.ValueA`

Comment: I'm not familiar with python , I'll go to understand what you are talking about.       Could you give me some references? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `t.contents` to get the object the pointer points to (TestStruct).  But I imagine you'd be even better off using Python's `struct` module for this (as @eryksun mentioned).

Comment: It looks like very ugly , imaging there are many struct like that.        In c/c++ , we can just write codes: TestStruct  test = (TestStruct)bytesBuf;

Comment: Ok, I got it . Thanks @Aleksandar !    I can get "TestStruct" object by using code "t.contents.ValueA" !

Comment: casting an immutable string is not a good idea. Use `t = TestStruct.from_buffer_copy(data)`. You also probably want to define the struct with `_pack_ = 1` to disable native alignment, and may need a `BigEndianStructure` if the `int` is in network order.

Comment: Or just use `ValueA, StringA = struct.unpack('>i9s', data)`.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun        The data which type is TestStruct will be received for many times , so I think the struct.unpack(...) cannot satisfied me for the efficiency is too low.   And could you tell me where is the function "from_buffer_copy" defined? For now I use the code: t = copy.deepcopy( cast( data, POINTER(TestStruct)).contents)

Comment: @NorSDNorSD, have you benchmarked the performance? You could edit your question with more information. Does `data` contain multiple records? Did you use `struct.unpack_from` with an offset? FYI, `from_buffer_copy` is documented here: [http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes#ctypes._CData.from_buffer_copy](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes#ctypes._CData.from_buffer_copy).